# Can i give conditions in contain in cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp

i m facing some problem in find function. im fetching value fro find function.i have model.contian another model .
Can i give conditions in contain in cakephp

is it possiblehi

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't really understand your question. Please can you expand it?

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->Post->find('all', array('contain' => array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'conditions' => array('Comment.author =' => "Daniel"),
        'order' => 'Comment.created DESC'
    )
)));
```

You should always [try the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1323/Containable) first :).

Comment: Where is this in the documentation, exactly? I am having similar trouble, and can't seem to get this to work as expected. (Maybe my expectations are wrong

Comment: I am sure you don't remember @anonymouscoward, but I think this was the right answer. Could you mark it as such?

Comment: The original question is not my  own, and thus I cannot do as you ask.

Comment: @anonymouscoward oh yeah sorry about that. Should've looked better.

Comment: I am sure you don't remember @Msofts, but I think this was the right answer. Could you mark it as such?

Answer (score 0):

isnt conditions in the format $this->ModelName->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Table.name'=>1))); working for you?

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can give conditions in contain